# extracting multiple data frames from a parallel structured list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, extract

My limited knowledge of lists is getting me in trouble. I have a list containing multiple data frames of differing lengths at each level, with a parallel structure, that looks like this:

```
list.fun <- function(y) {
  x1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20, mean=y))
  x2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, mean=y))
  return(list(x1=x1, x2=x2))
}
## make list  
foo <- lapply(1:3, list.fun)
```

I would like to extract all the data frames with the same name (in this case x1), assign labels as a new factor, and combine them into one single data frame. This manual approach works, but I am looking for something more generic.

```
## split results into into two data frames
b1 <- foo[[1]]$x1
b2 <- foo[[2]]$x1
b3 <- foo[[3]]$x1
b1$trial <- "t1"
b2$trial <- "t2"
b3$trial <- "t3"
## combine
bar <- rbind(d1, d2, d3)
```

Apologies if this has been asked already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the elements named `x1` using the `[[` operator:

```
lapply(foo, "[[", "x1")
```

You can then bind them together using `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(foo, '[[', "x1"))

> head(do.call(rbind, lapply(foo, '[[', "x1")))
          x
1 1.3599227
2 0.7760733
3 0.9852219
4 0.5447365
5 2.1185779
6 0.5419102
> nrow(do.call(rbind, lapply(foo, '[[', "x1")))
[1] 60
```

For your more general case:

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(foo)
                  , function(x){
                    out <- foo[[x]][['x1']]
                    out$trial <- paste0("t", x)
                    out
                  }
                  )
)


> head(res)
          x trial
1 1.3599227    t1
2 0.7760733    t1
3 0.9852219    t1
4 0.5447365    t1
5 2.1185779    t1
6 0.5419102    t1
```